How to remove duplicate results from JSON_Value results
If I had two tables:
PartDetails table
Id   Details                            Price   Brand Id
--------------------------------------------------------
1   {"partNumber":"012345","qty":14}    14.99          1
2   {"partNumber":"012345","qty":11}     4.88          1
3   {"partNumber":"44444","qty":1}       3.24          3
4   {"partNumber":"72431223","qty":9}    3.33          1
5   {"partNumber":"98989","qty":1}       3.33          2

Brands table:
Id   BrandName   
---------------
1   BrandOne
2   BrandTwo
3   BrandThree

I want to return Details.PartNumber, Details.Qty & BrandId from the PartDetailsTable, but also include the BrandName.
I have this working with:
SELECT DISTINCT 
    i.id,
    JSON_VALUE(i.Details, '$.partNumber') AS 'PartNumber', 
    i.BrandId, 
    b.Name AS 'BrandName',
    JSON_VALUE(i.Details, '$.qty') AS 'Qty', 
FROM
    PartDetailsTable i 
INNER JOIN 
    Brands b ON (i.BrandId = b.Id)

I want to remove duplicate part number records so for example in my PartDetailsTable above I would only want to return the rows with Id values of 1, 3, 4, 5.
Please, any advice? As Id 1 and 2 have the same partNumber of 012345, I don't need to sum the quantity or anything like that.

By the time of the 5th question, you really should drop this silly json structure and use a proper table design

Hey, thanks for the reply, just working with what I have

You could group it by the JSON_VALUE and then grab the MIN(index), the join back on that same table to grab the quantity
SELECT i.id,
    JSON_VALUE(i.Details, '$.partNumber') AS 'PartNumber', 
    i.BrandId, 
    b.Name AS 'BrandName',
    JSON_VALUE(i.Details, '$.qty') AS 'Qty', 
FROM (
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(Details, '$.partNumber') AS 'PartNumber', MIN(Id) [Id]
    FROM PartnerDetailsTable
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(Details, '$.qty') IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY JSON_VALUE(Details, '$.partNumber')
) gi
JOIN PartnerDetailsTable i
    ON i.Id = gi.Id
INNER JOIN Brands b 
    ON i.BrandId = b.Id
WHERE JSON_VALUE(i.Details, '$.qty') IS NOT NULL


Hey thanks for the reply, this still returns results if the qty is NULL (so '"qty": wont exist in the JSON), which I dont want.... how can we exclude this from the results?

Just a simple IS NOT NULL where condition. I've updated the example above.
